# Error parsing xml when namespace directives are present

Tags: node.js, xml-parsing, xmldom

I need to read multiple XML-files using node.js. When the root node contains namespace directives, parsing the xml file fails. When removing the namespace directives, all works well. All my files can have different declarations. How do I parse the XML, ignoring the namespace attributes? I need to use xPath to get some values.

I'm using ...

```
var fs = require('fs');
var xpath = require('xpath');
var dom   = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

var xml = fs.readFileSync('/test.xml', 'utf8').toString();
var doc = new dom().parseFromString(xml);
var id = xpath.select("/export/asset/id", doc);

console.log(id[0].firstChild.data);
```

XML-file

```
<export xmlns="some url" xmlns:xsi="some url" format="archive" version="2.4" xsi:schemaLocation="some url.xsd">
  <asset>
    <id>1445254514291</id>
    <name>test</name>
    <displayName />
    <origin>demo</origin>
  </asset>
<export>
```

Comment: Instead of trying to get around or ignore them - you seriously need to learn to **respect** and include the XML namespaces in your querying!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, taking into account namespaces is preferable, but if you have to deal with too many of these, one way to avoid them altogether is to use xpath and the somewhat convoluted, but effective, `local-name()` function.

So I would change

```
var id = xpath.select("/export/asset/id", doc);
```

to

```
var id = xpath.select("//*[local-name()='export']//*[local-name()='asset']//*[local-name()='id']", doc);
```

With the sample xml in the question, this should output:

```
"1445254514291"
```